# sharing code between microservices

Tags: node.js, docker, architecture

I have a suite i'm working on that has a few micro-services working togther.
I'm using Docker to setup the environment and it works great.

My project components are as follows:

- MongoDB
- Node.js worker that does some processing on the DB
- Node.js Rest API that serves the user

As you can probably guess the 2 Node.js servers are suppose to work with the same DB.
Now I've defined my models in one of the projects but I'm wondering what is the best practice when it comes to handling the second.
I would really love to avoid copy pasting my code because that means I have to keep both of them up to date when I do changes to the Schema.
is there a good way to share the code between them?

my project looks like this:

```
rest-api // My first Node.js application
    models
        MyFirstModel.js // This is identical to the one in the worker/models folder
        MySecondModel.js
    index.js
    package.json
    Dockerfile
worker // My second Node.js application
    models
        MyFirstModel.js
        MySecondModel.js
    index.js
    package.json
    Dockerfile
docker-compose.yml
```

Any input will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Why have you two separate applications? And why are the models identical?

Comment: as i've explaind. 2 micro services working with the same database

Comment: I meant why do you have two Microservices sharing a data model? Why isn't it just one? It feels like maybe a modelling problem rather than a technical one

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can.
What you have to do is to put your common files in an volume, and share this volume with both Node containers.

You should setup a data volume in which you put all the files you want to share. More about this [here](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/userguide/dockervolumes/) or anywhere else by googling it.
Cheers.

Comment: ok so i tried it and it does work but it complicates thing even further because i need to maintain another are in the code with it's on package.json for those shared models.. I'm hoping for a cleaner solution..

Comment: You only need to put the files you want to share in that data volume. So I don't understand what is your issue. Could you please give me more details ? ;-)

Comment: In my `common` folder there is the model file, it requires the `mongoose` module to create the Schema.. but when it tries to require it fails because there are no `node_modules` in the common directory. that means i need to add another layer of dependency management inside the common library

Comment: @dcohenb A possible workaround: put a cron script that will copy all files from the common folder into model folder. Otherwise I can't find a cleaner solution.

Comment: I am also trying my hand at creating a similar architecture (e.g. specific Docker containers running node service/processes [workers]) I would figure this to be a common problem with a common solution?

Answer (score 1):

The common opinion is the following: two microservices should not share same data model. There are several article about it and some question related to this topic.

[How to deal with shared models in micro service architectures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38554037/how-to-deal-with-shared-models-in-micro-service-architectures)

However I think there are some cases when you need it and acceptable. Trust is a luxury even if everything is internal, thus security and conformity must be considered. Any incoming object must be normalised, validated and checked before initiate any process with it. The two service should handle the data with the same way.

My solution that I used for an API and an Admin services which shared the models:
I created 3 repositories, one for the API and one for the Admin and a 3th one for the models directory. Models should be present in both repositories so and I added it as a git submodule. Whenever you change something on a schema, you should commit it separately, but I think it is the best solution to manage the changes without duplicating the code.

Comment: Actually the right way to do this is create a 3rd micro-service that acts as a gateway to the database. it will get CRUD requests to perform on the DB and take care of all the validation caching etc.